# Changing what I see on the Hot Question Widget

Tags: support, hot-questions, widgets, android-app-widgets

I've just recently started using the 4x1 (Hot Question) widget for the Stack Exchange app. Is there a way to modify which site's questions are featured on the widget? I've noticed a lot of questions come up that are from sites I have no experience with.